# Store and add value to variables

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP and i wanted make a basic slot machine, but when the winning number is equal to the user number the "money" variable (fake money) doesn't add the +10. It only stays at 50.

I have made a if statement and the user number is generated by `rand()`, but the `$currentValue =  $money + 10;` isn't working.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but what?

Example of the if statement:

```
if($winNr == $usrNr) {
    echo 'You won!';
    $currentValue = $money + 10;
    }
    else {
     echo 'Oops, try again';
     echo '<button onclick="window.location.reload()">Try again</button>';
     $currentValue = $money - 10;
}
```

Comment: Everytime the php page is loaded it resets the values to whatever you have `$money` defined as, which I guess is 50.  If you want it to increment up and behave like a game you should store the value `$money` in a database and update the values there.

Comment: Oh, i see. How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some way to store `$money` between page calls (i.e. a session), here's how to save it

```
if($winNr == $usrNr) {
    echo 'You won!';
    $money += 10;
    }
    else {
     echo 'Oops, try again';
     echo '<button onclick="window.location.reload()">Try again</button>';
     $money -= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to add numbers in PHP:

- $x+$y  simple addition
- $x++   add one to a number after loading the variable then reloading
  the variable
- ++$x   add one to the variable as it's loaded
- $x+=$y add y to x

for subtraction you can do similar things:

- $x-$y  simple subtraction
- $x--   subtract one from a number after loading the variable then reloading the variable
- --$x   subtract one from the variable as it's loaded
- $x-=$y subtract y from x

based upon what you're looking to do you want to do the following:

```
if($winNr == $usrNr) {
    echo 'You won!';
    $currentValue += 10;
    }
    else {
     echo 'Oops, try again';
     echo '<button onclick="window.location.reload()">Try again</button>';
     $currentValue -= 10;
}
```